# How to add Stylus "@import" support to IntelliJ

Tags: css, intellij-idea, stylus

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate Edition and I use [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) as a CSS preprocessor and I really would like to add IntelliJ support for the Stylus' `@import` feature

**Example**

`colors.styl` contains

```
$nice-color = lightgreen
```

and `foo.styl` contains

```
@import "colors"
body
  background-color $nice-color
```

This will evaluate to a css like this

```
body {
  background-color: #90EE90
}
```

**Question**

My IDE will show me a nice little color-preview box next to the line-numbers in the editor.
But this only works for the `colors.styl` file, where the color is defined.
(https://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/colorPreview.png)

I really would love to see the same preview-box in the `foo.styl` file, where I import and actually use this color. I already installed the Stylus plugin for IntelliJ.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without changing the source of the Stylus IDEA plugin.